# How to select a row(object) based on max of a field Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

am trying to get a row (object) based on the max of `RollNumber` which is a long `Datatype field`. i expect it to return a null object in case there isn't any so i used `SingleorDefault`.But it seems my query is all wrong(work in progress on linq here).
here is the query:

```
SchoolContextExpress db = new SchoolContextExpress();
        Profile profile = db.Profiles.Where(p => p.RollNumber == db.Profiles.Max(r=>r.RollNumber)).SingleOrDefault();
```

thanks for reading this.

Comment: Looks ok to me.  What's the problem?

Comment: Well, works fine here! Do you get an error?

Comment: Contains more than one element

Comment: Do you have duplicate roll numbers?

Comment: Ahah! there are empty, index allows empty row. the reason why they are left empty is because in my business logic i would like to validate the registration before issuing the roll number. So on registration , everything is saved but the rollnumber is left empty (zero in this long context). How can i work around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To work with empty RollNumber...

```
Profile profile = db.Profiles.Where(p => p.RollNumber !=0 &&  p.RollNumber == db.Profiles.Max(r=>r.RollNumber)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Or you may want to consider...

```
Profile profile = db.Profiles.Where(p => p.RollNumber == db.Profiles.Where(p1 => p1.RollNumber != 0).Max(r=>r.RollNumber)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: i guess i would do different from zero then since RollNumber is long. is that ok?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do beside the first answer:

```
Profile profile = db.Profiles.OrderByDescending(p => p.RollNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```